# onmouseover action on event registration

Tags: javascript, jquery

When an element gets an onmouseover event registered, it doesn't trigger if the mouse is over the element during the register, until the mouse moves.  I know that after you register it, you can check if the mouse is over and trigger the event with some extra code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit #1: response to first comment

I mean that Ideally there would be some sort of way to do this without manually checking if the mouse is over the element and manually triggering a fake onmouseover event.  Is there a better way to accomplish this functionality in a standard way?  Maybe a library that already thought of this?

Comment: I don't get your point. Might you be interested in elaborating it further?

Comment: Have you tried onfocus?

Comment: Does onfocus trigger if you register it while an element already has focus?  I haven't tried on focus, just tried onmouseover.

Comment: If you have the focus, it should work.

Comment: Ok, but onmouseover is also used for hovering over a div to move an element while on focus only works for input elements.  Are you implying that its a bug or inconsistency in the API?

Comment: That seems correct in my opinion too. Maybe try mouseenter - https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Maybe an inconsistency, but I don't think its a bug. They must have been fully aware about it.